# Formatting text help button in chat comments should be easier to see

Tags: feature-request, chat, markdown, help-text

I noticed there is no clear way on how to format text in chat comments. When it comes to Questions and Answers there is a formatting tool bar and also a question mark button with more help. Even comments have a help button that displays information on how to format the comment.

However, when it comes to chat comments the help button happens to be too far away from the actual comment textarea:

[image]

Probably moving it below the send button, just as in non-chat comments would make the trick.

Also note that the help button where it is currently located is not related to the other buttons it is next to (faq, legal, etc) but related to the send and upload buttons.